# Where does git clone stores temporary files ,when cloning remote repository to local?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, git, svn

I am trying to clone repository,with size 500MB. When we run command

> `git clone https://repository.com/repo dir`

It will show status cloning, speed and how much data cloned (250MiB|2MiB/s ). But actual directory where it is being cloned will remain empty(except .git) until clone completes. Where does it will store cloned files meanwhile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository consists of two parts:

- Refs (name-to-hash mappings) – they're small, so they are kept in memory while downloading, then saved to `.git/packed-refs` and/or `.git/refs/*` afterwards.
- Pack (compressed history archive) – written to `.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_<random>` while downloading, later renamed to `.git/objects/pack/pack-<id>.pack` once the download is complete.

Worktree files on a brand-new clone are always identical to the topmost commit's contents, so they aren't downloaded separately – they're simply extracted from `.git/objects/*` using the same packfile that was just downloaded.

Comment: What about Refs, are they destroyed once command completes?

Comment: No, they're also written out to files in `.git/`.